# how to kill twisted protocol instances python

Tags: python, twisted, instance

I have a server application written in python using twisted and I'd like to know how to kill instances of my protocol (bottalk).  Everytime I get a new client connection, I see the instance in memory (print Factory.clients) .. but let's say I want to kill one of those instances from the server side (drop a specific client connection)?  Is this possible?  I've tried looking for a phrase using lineReceived, then if it matches, self.transport.loseConnection().  But that doesn't seem to reference the instance anymore or something..

```
class bottalk(LineReceiver):

    from os import linesep as delimiter

    def connectionMade(self):
            Factory.clients.append(self)
            print Factory.clients

    def lineReceived(self, line):
            for bots in Factory.clients[1:]:
                    bots.message(line)
            if line == "killme":
                    self.transport.loseConnection()

    def message(self, message):
            self.transport.write(message + '\n')

class botfactory(Factory):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
            return bottalk()

Factory.clients = []

stdio.StandardIO(bottalk())

reactor.listenTCP(8123, botfactory())

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You closed the TCP connection by calling `loseConnection`.  But there's no code anywhere in your application that removes items from the `clients` list on the factory.

Try adding this to your protocol:

```
def connectionLost(self, reason):
    Factory.clients.remove(self)
```

This will remove the protocol instance from the `clients` list when the protocol's connection is lost.

Also, you should consider not using the global `Factory.clients` to implement this functionality.  It's bad for all the usual reasons globals are bad.  Instead, give each protocol instance a reference to *its* factory and use that:

```
class botfactory(Factory):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        protocol = bottalk()
        protocol.factory = self
        return protocol

factory = botfactory()
factory.clients = []

StandardIO(factory.buildProtocol(None))

reactor.listenTCP(8123, factory)
```

Now each `bottalk` instance can use `self.factory.clients` instead of `Factory.clients`.

Comment: can't edit the last comment, so here's this one.  i'm still stuck on, loseConnection() doesn't close the instance.  i know loseConnection() works, as for a test i stuck it in connectionMade(), and all new client connections instantly dropped.  but, i'm still having the issue of how to tell loseConnection() which instance i want to close.  you're dead on with the instance clean up after it's loseConnection(), thanks!  but how do i make loseConnection() work on a specific instance?  thanks for the great advice too.  i'm digesting this.

Comment: loseConnection closes the connection represented by the transport instance you call it on.  `transport.loseConnection()` closes the connection represented by `transport`.  `anotherTransport.loseConnection()` closes the connection represented by `anotherTransport`.  `bottalkInstance.transport.loseConnection()` closes the connection represented by `bottalkInstance.transport`, which by convention is the transport `bottalkInstance` is interacting with (ie, receiving bytes from and sending bytes to).  This is true whether the name of the bottalk instance variable is `bottalkInstance` or `self`.

Comment: you made it make perfect sense!  a twisted lesson and a python lesson all in one.  Thanks!